# Unable to identify what's wrong with this code

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have this code:`

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        for (var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
            var group_name = myObj[i]["display_name"];
            var group_icon = myObj[i]["icon"];
            function insert_grp_icon(){
                 var src = document.getElementById("list");
                 var img = document.createElement("img");
                 var abc = group_icon;
                 img.src = "xyz.com" + abc;
                 src.appendChild(img);
            };
            document.getElementById("list").innerHTML +=  group_name + insert_grp_icon() ;
        }
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "get-category-api.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>`
```

Here, the "get-category-api.txt" contains a JSON response. It's an array of objects.

I need to add the icon just after the name is displayed (by group_name) and the icon's URL is stored in "icon". For some reason, it's returning "undefined".

Somehow, the insert_grp_icon() isn't working.

Any insight on this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `insert_grp_icon()` be returning something?

Comment: It seems that *insert_grp_icon* appends an image to `#list`, so the function doesn't have to return anything. If you want the name first, append it as a text node, then append the icon.

Comment: @RobG, you're right. I missed that one.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Yes. Everything's fine.

Comment: @RobG I was not sure what text node was. So, I looked it up, implemented it but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting much help because you haven't created a [*minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

So I've done that and created some test data.

You should move the *insert_grp_icon* function declaration outside the loop, then pass it the parameters it needs. If you want the image after the icon, then insert the image, then add the name as a text node.

I've also inserted a new line between images and names, but whether you want that or not is up to you.

```js
// var myObj = JSON.parse(responseText);
var myObj = [
  {display_name: 'foo', icon: 'a.jpg'},
  {display_name: 'bar', icon: 'b.jpg'},
];

// Define function outside loop
// Creates an image and appends it to target
function insert_grp_icon(target, group_icon) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  var abc = group_icon;
  img.src = "xyz.com" + abc;
  target.appendChild(img);
}

for (var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
  var group_name = myObj[i]["display_name"];
  var group_icon = myObj[i]["icon"];
  var target = document.getElementById("list");

  // If not the first one, insert a new line
  if (i > 0) target.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

   // Append image to target
   insert_grp_icon(target, group_icon);

  // Append group_name as text
  target.appendChild(document.createTextNode(group_name));
}
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```